# Android Cannot dispatch touch events to Spinner

Tags: java, android, junit, spinner, motionevent

I am writing an Android JUnit test that iterates through a list of MotionEvents and dispatches them to the Activity under test.  For most events, I can just use the activity.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent) method.  For dialogs, I have to obtain the dialog in memory and call the dispatchTouchEvent directly.  I am having trouble with android.widget.Spinner objects.  The dispatchTouchEvent method seems to getting ignored.

For example, a Spinner (Mode = DIALOG) appears on the screen, the test code is dispatching a MotionEvent with the proper (x, y) coordinates and actions (ACTION_DOWN followed by ACTION_UP):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) activity.findViewById(R.id.spinnerId);
spinner.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent); //returns true, but Spinner has not been touched

View v = spinner.getChildAt(0);
v.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);  //returns false, Spinner has not been touched
```

For now, I'm using Robotium to directly click the Spinner, but this is not desired for long term.  Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you use spinner.performClick(); instead of spinner.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent); ?

Comment: The idea is to capture all of the motion events. (e.g. ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_UP, ACTION_MOVE). The user might scroll through the Spinner before making a choice.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe you could do dispatch event on Activity level passing as x,y for instance center of spinner(Robotium do that but passing motionEvent via Instrumentation rather then activity).